# Named entity recognition including context in Python with nltk

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have a text and want to extract the named entities including the context using nltk with Python 3.6. 
The following example should illustrate what I mean:

```
import nltk

text = 'the Iraqi people'
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tag_tokens = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
named_entities = nltk.ne_chunk(tag_tokens, binary=True)

print(named_entities)
```

Running this code gives me

```
(S the/DT (NE Iraqi/NNP) people/NNS)
```

However, I want to my algorithm to recognise 'Iraqi people' as one named entity, i.e.

```
(S the/DT (NE Iraqi/NNP people/NNS))
```

Right now my best guess about how to go about this is to look through the list of pos-tagged tokens and make chunks out of nouns, that follow proper nouns. 
Is there a better way of going about this, or maybe even a library I don't know of?

Comment: i haven't used NLTK, but the results you show look like sentence chunking results, not NER results. Are you sure there is not another call in the API to get Named Entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ne_chunk` stands for NLTK’s currently recommended named entity chunker which is some statistical model. That means

- sometimes it might be wrong
- it might be trained to predict different things than you would like it to predict

Unfortunately you can't modify the model. So you are left with two options:
Either you train your own model, which is going to be a lot of work. Or you use some heuristics, for example the one you are proposing.

As to which heuristic to use, it depends on your application. However, generally speaking, errors shouldn't surprise you...